# Vim: quit if buffer list is empty

Tags: vim

I'd like `:bd` and `:bw` to actually quit my vim session if, after the current buffer is removed, the buffer list is empty (i.e. if, before executing `:bd` or `:bw`, I only had the current buffer in the buffer list). How can I accomplish this? I'd assume it should be pretty easy, but googling hasn't really yielded anything useful, and so far I haven't managed to write an `autocmd` to accomplish this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To check for a single buffer, you need to iterate over all potential buffers and check whether they are still *listed* (e.g. in `:ls`). The check is triggered whenever a buffer is deleted:

```
:autocmd BufDelete * if len(filter(range(1, bufnr('$')), '! empty(bufname(v:val)) && buflisted(v:val)')) == 1 | quit | endif
```

Comment: I managed to hack something together myself, but thanks for the one-line version. However, in order to get exactly the behavior I want, I need to change `== 1` to `== 2` (the same is true in my solution as well). Any idea why this would be? Does `bufnr` always include the "empty" buffer, and does `buflisted` return true for the empty buffer?

Comment: Yes, the empty buffer counts, too. In my solution, you therefore have to `:bdelete` it, too, for Vim to quit. Using `2` might fail if you start Vim with a `file` argument; then, no empty buffer exists. Better add a `! empty(bufname(v:val)) && buflisted(...` to the filter.

Comment: Sorry, one more thing: it appears that this is preventing me from opening the help window when I have exactly one item in my buffer list. Any idea why that would be? I wouldn't even expect the BufDelete event to occur when opening the help doc...

Comment: I had the same issue and had to add the empty check, i.e.: autocmd BufDelete * if len(filter(range(1, bufnr('$')), 'empty(bufname(v:val)) && buflisted(v:val)')) == 1 | quit | endif

Comment: With these solutions, I cannot open help when only one buffer is open.

Answer (score 1):

The proposed solution might be problematic in respect to some plugins. 
This is the shortcut that did it for me and it seems to be more safe as it doesn't rely on autocmds:

```
nn q :if ((len(filter(range(1, bufnr('$')), 'buflisted(v:val)')) == 1) && expand('%') == '')<Bar>exe 'q'<Bar>else<Bar>exe 'bd'<Bar>endif<cr>
```

It uses `bd` unless there is a single buffer with no name when it uses `quit` instead.

Comment: I don't see why `:e` would cause vim to exit using the proposed `QuitIfLastBuffer()` function and `BufDelete` autocommand, unless you have something that would cause `:e` to trigger `BufDelete`. Also, your solution isn't quite the same--it looks like you're changing the behavior of `:q`, whereas the question and prior solutions are about changing the behavior of `:bd`.

Comment: You are right, this was plugin interaction with unite. I guess the solution is problematic with some plugins. I changed the info to note this.

Answer (score 0):

modify from above:

```
    func  Smart_qq()
        if expand('%') == '' && ( len( filter( range(1, bufnr('$')),  'buflisted(v:val)' ) )  == 1 )
            exe 'quit!'
        else
            exe 'bdel!'
        endif
    endfunc

    nn  qq :call Smart_qq()<cr>
    vn  qq :call Smart_qq()<cr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to do this via a mapping.

There are two versions, one asking to save, and one quitting forcefully:

```
" Close the current buffer, quit vim if it's the last buffer
" Pass argument '!" to do so without asking to save
function! CloseBufferOrVim(force='')
  if len(filter(range(1, bufnr('$')), 'buflisted(v:val)')) == 1
    exec ("quit" . a:force)
    quit
  else
    exec ("bdelete" . a:force)
  endif
endfunction

nnoremap <silent> <Leader>q :call CloseBufferOrVim()<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <Leader>Q :call CloseBufferOrVim('!')<CR>
```